# How do I write a java program that will convert a CSV file off all the covid 19 data into JSON

Tags: java, json, csv, iso

They want us to use a combination of ArrayList (or a regular array) and one of the Map Collections Hashmap or Tree Map. The conversion will involve reading the data file line by line reading it into the appropriate structure. Do this in a method called read_records. When the structure is filled, then send the structure to a method called print_records which will print it out in the following format:

```
"ABW" :  { 
"2020-03-13" :  {
    "iso_code" : "ABW",
    "location" : "Aruba",
    "date" : "2020-03-13",
    "total_cases" : "2",
    "new_cases" : "2",
    "total_deaths" : "0",
    "new_deaths" : "0",
    "total_cases_per_million" : "18.733",
    "new_cases_per_million" : "18.733",
    "total_deaths_per_million" : "0.0",
    "new_deaths_per_million" : "0.0",
    "total_tests" : "",
    "new_tests" : "",
    "total_tests_per_thousand" : "",
    "new_tests_per_thousand" : "",
    "new_tests_smoothed" : "",
    "new_tests_smoothed_per_thousand" : "",
    "tests_units" : "",
    "stringency_index" : "0.0",
    "population" : "106766.0",
    "population_density" : "584.8",
    "median_age" : "41.2",
    "aged_65_older" : "13.085",
    "aged_70_older" : "7.452",
    "gdp_per_capita" : "35973.781",
    "extreme_poverty" : "",
    "cvd_death_rate" : "",
    "diabetes_prevalence" : "11.62",
    "female_smokers" : "",
    "male_smokers" : "",
    "handwashing_facilities" : "",
    },
    .
    .
    .
},
.
.
.
```

Structure the program so that appropriate methods are used in a class called JSONParser. Ensure good program structure by dividing the processing into separate methods for reading, writing and or analyzing the input data.

Heres the code I have so far:

```
public class CSVParser {
    private final int ISO_CODE = 0;
    private final int DATE = 2;

    public CSVParser(File f) throws FileNotFoundException {
        try {
            Scanner covid_data = new Scanner(f);
            String header = covid_data.nextLine();

            while(covid_data.hasNextLine()) {
                String line = covid_data.nextLine();
                String record[] = line.split(",");
                String date = record[DATE];
                System.out.println(record[ISO_CODE] + ":");

                for(String s : record) System.out.println("       "+s);
                System.out.println();
            }

            covid_data.close();

        } catch(FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.println("Problem with file"); 
        }
    }
}
```

Heres the Main Class:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;

/*
 *
Put the header comment here
*/
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        File f = new File("owid-covid-data.csv");
        CSVParser csvfile = new CSVParser(f);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a code writing service. Please indicate a specific problem that you would like help solving.

Comment: Im aware this is not a code writing service I do not want people to tell me exactly what to do I just wanted a general idea of what I should try. What I'm having the most trouble with is making the program single out entries based on iso code and date. I have figured out how to print it out into a hash map. But if this is not the place to ask for ideas then I guess I will look elsewhere.